# Equivalent consumer config parameters for rebalancing tuning in Kafka 0.9.0+

Tags: apache-kafka, kafka-consumer-api

In Kafka 0.8.2, I used the following parameters to allow my consumer group some more time to properly rebalance when necessary:

```
{
...
"rebalance.max.retries": "6",
"rebalance.backoff.ms": "10000",
...
}
```

As of version 0.9.0, Kafka uses the the "New consumer config", which no longer includes these options. I'm looking to achieve the same effect now that I'm using version 0.10.2. How can I allow my consumer group more time and retries when trying to rebalance?